# Why for loop with cached length is slower than simple for loop?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am reading the book "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja". But I am confused with the figure that I found on in this book. From my view, simple for loop lost time to get the length of array so if the length is cached before, the speed would be improved. But the picture below showed the opposite result. Could someone give me the reason? .Thanks.
[image: for loop and for loop with cached length speed test]

Comment: We are talking about 7% difference and 5% accuracy. I would say that both results are actually equal.

Comment: And what is the loop length?

Comment: the cached length is calculated everytime it do a loop, the simple loop don't calculate the length as it already set in the len variable

Comment: @epascarello both iterate over the same array

Comment: Obviously, storing/retrieving variables from any scope (dependingly) causes some decrease in performance. It's like using the Boolean constructor to declare a `false` variable.

Comment: @messerbill .... really ...

Comment: @Angel that would explain why the second one would be faster...but it is not

Comment: I don't like these short code performance tests on jsperf at all. Imho they say close to nothing. Most of these posted on stackoverflow are not done with the care needed to actually get any real information.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?

Comment: It is a sarcastic response because I wanted to know what the loop is actually doing. 1 item, 100000 items, etc

Comment: @epascarello >.< sometimes i don't get stuff like that :D

Comment: a) Browsers are really good at optimising idiomatic code (i.e. caching the `.length` access themselves when they see it doesn't change) b) your `i` variable is global which will slow down things a lot

Comment: And a lot of the performance stuff comes from a time when browsers' engines were very very crappy at optimization. 10 years ago that would have made a huge difference, modern times, not so much.

Comment: Remember: the length of an array is usually stored, not computed, which isn't the same for a list. Looping on a NodeList might give you different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance in js is a question of how much the engine optimized the code. And how the engine optimizes code depends on the developers that wrote the optimization. And those developers want the average code to run fast, that means the more "normal" your code is, the faster it runs. So maybe iterating over an array in the first way is so common that someone heavily optimized it. Whatsoever the only real result we can gain from that data is: both ways are fast enough to not care about the difference.

Comment: good answer - but i guess this is not just a js specific thing, but in any language, isn't it?

Comment: @messerbill assembly :)

Comment: @JonasW. Even in assembly, different instructions take different times due to different microcode and caching pipelines and the more common ones are faster than the unusual ones.

Comment: Even on assembly the branch predictor implementation might hit on one processor and not on another. Or you get wrong processor affinity for the first few seconds. Or a OS/driver code has some hickup during your test. Or ...

Comment: at least @JonasW. 's expectation is right at the binary code :)